# Implementing bootstrap Model

Tags: php, javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

i have a php page that displaying a table from my Data base i like to use a delete button.
like this :https://i.stack.imgur.com/laZZP.png
this button must display a confirmation window (yes/no) for that i use the Bootstrap Modal.
like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zlf9y.png
How can i use the yes button to delete the selected article?

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the click event on yes button.
Lets say that the yes button has the Id `Yes`. A code similar to the following can be used.

```
$("#Yes").click(function() {
    //your ajax call, or any desired implementation
});
```

jQuery is used in the above code so make sure that you add jQuery in your project.

Comment: i can get the id of the article, but how can i store it to use it in the yes button then execute the query ?